# How to use a function pointer to return a function pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

I was studying signal handling in unix and came across this

```
void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int);
```

I dont understand this prototype and how this returns a pointer to a function.

I also read this answer:
[How do function pointers in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work) but it's not clear to me.

It's supposed to return a function pointer but I dont understand where it specifies the return type as another function pointer.
The way I see it is that, if I use `(*foo(int n))` in a function definition the return type of this function `foo(int n)` becomes a function pointer.Is this correct?
Is there a simpler example for this?

Comment: Also: [the cdecl explanation](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=void+%28*signal%28int%2C+void+%28*%29%28int%29%29%29%28int%29)

Comment: Also, the return type becomes a function pointer by adding a parameter list after the function signature. (Which already contains an unrelated parameter list.) Compare [`void (*foo(int))`](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=void+%28%2Afoo%28int%29%29) (which is the same as `void *foo(int)` but not `void (*foo)(int)`) and [`void (*foo(int))(long)`](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=void+%28*foo%28int%29%29%28long%29). To put it another way: the return type of a function is the stuff *outside* the signature, not just to the left of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, let's look at how a function pointer is declared.

```
return-type (*function-name)(parameter-list);
```

In the declaration you posted, there are two function-pointer types in play. The first is a parameter that's passed into a function that matches the `signal` prototype:

```
void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int);
//                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Let's rename that function pointer type to `handler` and give it its own declaration.

```
typedef void (*handler)(int);
void (*signal(int sig, handler func))(int);
```

Now we can break down the rest of the declaration. The "inside" part is the actual function declaration:

```
...signal(int sig, handler func)...
```

And the "outside" describes the function pointer it returns:

```
void (...)(int);
```

This is also the same function-pointer type as our `handler` type, so with that `typedef` in place, we could redeclare the `signal` function like this:

```
handler signal(int sig, handler func);
```

(Much prettier.)

Comment: ... which is a `handler` as well - or am I wrong?

Comment: It is indeed. Let me amend my post to make that a little clearer.

Answer (score 1):

```
void (*signal(stuff))(int)
```

declares signal as returning a pointer to a function that takes an int as an argument and returns void. The stuff gives the arguments to signal, which in this case are

```
(int sig, void (*func)(int))
```

That is, the first argument to the function signal is an int, and the second argument is a function pointer taking an int as an argument and returning void.

Edit: Thus, if you made some call -- for example,

```
void foo (int x) {
    return;
}
void *bar = (*signal)(0, &foo);
```

then bar will be a pointer to a function taking an int and returning nothing, and as such can be called as follows:

```
(*bar)(0);
```

Comment: You don't need to `*` dereference if you call a function pointer. Just do `bar(0)` and you are fine.

Comment: True, but I find that it helps with remembering what's going on in large projects.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `typedef` to simplify the function pointer definition, which can help you to understand the long and complicated definition.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef void (*func)(int);
typedef void (*rtype)(int);

void myfunc(int a)
{
    printf("A is %d\n", a);
}

// thus signal can be defined as this
// exactly the same as in your question
rtype signal(int a, func handler)
{
    return myfunc;
}

int main()
{
    signal(0, 0)(12);
    return 0;
}
```

the above code should output: `A is 12`;

Hope helps!